# Configure Github webhook to Digital Ocean

Tags: github, lamp, digital-ocean, webhooks

Ok, so I have configured a Digital Ocean droplet as per the following guides:

- Initial Server Setup with Ubuntu 16.04
- Install LAMP stack on Ubuntu 16.04
- Secure apache with let's encrypt

In summary: I have a LAMP server, I have a domain pointed at my LAMP server, it is https now, and I can ssh into it with an account I created (not root) and it has things like UFW enabled.

Goal:
I want to setup a webhook from github, such that when things are merged into master, this gets relayed to the droplet.

Config:

My webroot lay at: /var/www/domain-name.com/public_html

- I can confirm that when I put an index.html file there, it works

I have a working ssh connection between the github repo and my DO server.

- The id_rsa and id_rsa.pub lay in `~/.ssh` of my server (this is with my user, not root, if that matters).
- Github confirms that this connection is valid (it's green)

Where it breaks down:

- I have tried a number of tutorials which I am linking to below
- [Portent - GitHub Auto-Deploy Setup Guide](https://www.portent.com/blog/design-dev/github-auto-deploy-setup-guide.htm)
- [Behind Companies - simple script for deploy](http://behindcompanies.com/2014/01/a-simple-script-for-deploying-code-with-githubs-webhooks/)

Those are two distinct methods. But in essence, one says to use a `deploy.php` file and the other says to use `webhook.php` in different configurations. They appear distinct from one another. In essence though, I load them on the server, configure them (e.g. - change paths, etc.) and then point github to them.

In both cases github sees them (it goes green sorta). But in both cases, I am unable to get them to actually work. I test this by pushing changes from localhost up to github, merging into master (also tried committing directly onto master just in case). I get nothing server side, no change. I should mention that to start I get the repo onto my server with a git clone (making sure I use ssh and not https). Also my server has been configured to know my git username and email.

Finally, I should add that both guides I am using appear to want me to take action with www-data, but they don't describe much of why or even how. And some of the commands they tell me to run don't actually work. Also, the Portent guide wants me to save the .ssh keys in an odd spot (in my opinion, I almost think it's an error).

Conclusion / Request:

- Is there a good guide for accomplishing what I want
- Short of this, is there a good place to start to debug (I see in github that these hook events are green and think they are working (?).
- Ideally, is there a simple step by step anyone can recommend that will help me do this.

Thank you. I am so close to having a more substantial method for developing websites. Would love to get this last piece finished. Any help you can provide will be amazing.

Sorry about lack of links to digital ocean docs, as a newbie I'm restricted to two links.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up going with:

Step 1

Setup an Ubuntu 16.04 x64 droplet with SSL encryption via Digital Ocean

- [Initial Server Setup with Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/initial-server-setup-with-ubuntu-16-04)
- [Install LAMP stack on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04)
- How To Secure Apache with Let's Encrypt on Ubuntu 16.04

In summary - You now have a Digital Ocean Droplet fully configured.

Step 2

Via SSH - Configure the Droplet

Make an `.ssh` directory in `/var/www` and give permissions to www-data user:

`sudo mkdir /var/www/.ssh`

`sudo chown www-data /var/www/.ssh`

Switch user to www-data:

`sudo -u www-data bash`

`cd /var/www/.ssh`

Generate an ssh keypair that will connect your server (via www-data) and your Github project:

`ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "IDENTIFY THE KEY BY REPO"`

I also like to name it id_rsa_REPONAME.pub so that identifying the keypairs is easier

`cat id_rsa_REPONAME.pub`

Copy that and paste it as a deploy key in your Github Repos settings.

You also need to add this keypair to your `config` file

`vim config` will create or allow you to edit this file if it already exists. You need this config to help your server match incoming ssh requests from github.

Add codeblock:

`Host REPONAME github.com
Hostname github.com
IdentityFile /var/www/.ssh/id_rsa_REPONAME`

Save and exit.

`ssh -T git@github.com`

Should output `Hi YOURGITUSERNAME/REPONAME! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.`

This confirms that specific deploy key can be found by github. You can also see it highlighted in green on the github side.

`exit` (this drops you out of www-data and back into your user account)

`chown www-data:www-data /the/path/to/public_html`

Switch back into www-data to do the initial cloning of the repo:

`sudo -u www-data bash`

`cd /the/path/to/public_html`

Before you clone

Make sure you have a file named `githubdeploy.php` in the root of your repo

`` <?php `git pull`;?> ``

`git clone THE_REPO_SSH_URL`

`exit` (this drops you out of www-data and back into your user account)

On Github:

Add the url path to githubdeploy.php as a webhook in your Github Repos settings.

DONE

Comment: Would love to hear from anyone if this has fatal security concerns. Again, I recognize that this is not proper for continuous deployment. But it's a setup I want for a particular situation.

Comment: [Verify the requests](https://help.github.com/articles/github-s-ip-addresses/#service-hook-ip-addresses) to prevent anyone from hitting that endpoint